# How often does Blazors runtime need to be shipped to the client?

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to decide on a framework for our next website/web application. I've decided to use a framework that would make it easy to build a single page application. The reason being is that we were given a single server with limited resources (I'm trying to push as much processing as possible to the client while at the same time minimizing bandwidth consumption).

I've stumbled upon MS Blazor and started reading up on it. It seems to fit all my requirements but there is one that stands out to me.

On the post "[Pros and cons of Blazor for web development](https://scientificprogrammer.net/2019/08/18/pros-and-cons-of-blazor-for-web-development/)" a con that was mentioned was "Requires the whole runtime to be shipped". How often does the runtime gets shipped to the user? Once per visit? Each time they clear / lose their cache? Each time MS puts out an update?

I can get users to wait patiently while the runtime downloads  (from the same post "a couple of lines of code is guaranteed to be quite a few megabytes in size."), but it would defeat my purpose if this was every time they visited the site.

Note: The project is to migrate a WPS desktop application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only applies to Blazor WebAssembly. The server-side version has a very tiny footprint.

The runtime would be heavily cached, and most likely come from a cdn (being shared).

So the users would need to download again after clearing/losing their cache or when *you* decide to upgrade to a newer version.

But it's only ~2MB, it's not the full framework. You might find JPGs of that size on the web too.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now leaning heavily towards this solution.